# How to release ios app by react native

Tags: ios, facebook, reactjs, react-native, release

I read documents of react native and I have built a file apk with [this tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-building-from-source.html#content). But i don't see tutorial for how to release ios app with my code react native. I'm a newbie so I hope anyone can show me step by step to release ios app with react native pls. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: use **fastlane**.

Here is why:

Especially as a newbie i can recommend you to use [fastlane-tools](http://fastlane.tools).
Fastlane contains tools that helps you with the signing process of the app where you need certificates and provisioning profiles. This is normally a very very complex process with lot of pitfalls, but fastlane makes it easygoing with some simple commands.

Some good tutorials about using fastlane together with react native:

- https://dbanck.svbtle.com/deploying-a-react-native-app-with-fastlane
  https://weluse.de/blog/react-native-deployment-with-fastlane.html